# Compare values from two List<String> in Java

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist

I have a problem with getting the value from a list. For example, I create an `ArrayList` from a `ResultSet`. I want to compare the values of this `ResultSet` to another `ResultSet`. My approach is to convert the `ResultSet`s to `ArrayList`s and then compare them.I already used `String.append()` but failed to obtain the string.
**How to get the value from from the `ArrayList`?**
**Can a simple solution be provided?**

my code:

main class:

```
String my_query = "SELECT * FROM test.test_application";

Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
Boolean result = false;

DatabaseConnection cc = new DatabaseConnection();
connection = cc.connect();

if (connection != null) {
    pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(my_query);
    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

    TestingModel tm = new TestingModel();
    Gson gs = new Gson();
    ArrayList<TestingModel> list = new ArrayList<TestingModel>();

    while(rs.next()) {
        tm.setClientID(rs.getInt(1));
        tm.setClientName(rs.getString(2));
        tm.setClientAddress(rs.getString(3));
        tm.setClientTelpNumber(rs.getString(4));
        tm.setClientEmail(rs.getString(5));
        list.add(tm);
    }
    System.out.println(gs.toJson(list));

    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(string.append(list.get(i).toString()));
    }
}
```

model:

```
public class TestingModel {

    private int clientID;
    private String clientName;
    private String clientAddress;
    private String clientTelpNumber;
    private String clientEmail;
    // setter and getter
}
```

Comment: override the toString() method inside the TestingModel class, So, it will be than easier to compare two TestingModel objects, like if(obj1.equals(obj2)){ }

Comment: @ArifMustafa You mean the `equals()` method?

Comment: @Shankhadeep Ghoshal yes, you heard the sound right...

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to override the `equals(Object obj)` method in your `TestingModel` class. There,you can use the `String.equals(String s)` or `String.equalsIgnoreCase(String s)` depending on your need and also check for equality of other data members.

In you main class, simply iterate through the '`List`s that you have obtained from the `ResultSet`s and call the equals method.

References:

- [String comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)
- [Comparing ArrayLists of same type of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853121/how-to-compare-two-array-lists-for-similar-objects-which-differ-in-at-least-one)